# How to add multiple reactions to embed Discord JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am sending a discord embed using JDA and the following code:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(image.build()).queue();
```

I can add a single reaction to the message by changing the code to this:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(image.build()).complete().addReaction("✔").queue();
```

How can I add multiple reactions to this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Message` object returned by `complete()` multiple times.

So, you can just send the reactions one after another:

```java
Message msg=event.getChannel().sendMessage(image.build()).complete();
msg.addReaction("✔").queue();
msg.addReaction("+1").queue();
```

This uses complete, however and will wait until the message has been sent. No listeners are executed during that time.

This means that your bot waits and other commands (by other users) are executed only after the message has been sent.

In order to fix that, you can use `.queue()` with a lambda:

```java
event.getChannel().sendMessage(image.build()).queue(msg->{
    msg.addReaction("✔").queue();
    msg.addReaction("+1").queue();
});
```

If you want to do this multiple times, you can write a method for this:

```java
public void sendMessageWithReactions(MessageChannel channel,MessageEmbed embed, String... reactions){
    channel.sendMessage(embed).queue(msg->{
        for(String reaction:reactions){
            msg.addReaction(reaction).queue();
        }
    });
}
```

You can call this method like this: `sendMessageWithReactions(event.getChannel(),image.build(),"✔","+1");`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to implement either of your solutions but am experiencing issues. I'm getting a cannot resolve symbol 'Message' for the first solution and something about lambda expressions not being supported at level 5 for the second. any ideas?

Comment: I fixed the lambda issue and got it working thanks!

Comment: You need to import `Message`. Add `import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;` before your class declaration.